# Specify fixed relative positions for nodes

Tags: graph, graphviz

I want to draw a graph using some engine (neato looks best right now), but constrain the engine to maintain some relative positions between nodes. For example, if my graph has a cycle of length 5 in it, I want to specify that this cycle should be drawn like a pentagram with a certain size, and the engine should draw graphs satisfying this constraint.
Is there any software that can do this?

EDIT: Example

Input

```
strict graph  {
"(1, 2, 3, 4)" [shape=circle];
"(1, 2, 4, 3)" [shape=circle];
"(1, 3, 2, 4)" [shape=circle];
"(1, 3, 4, 2)" [shape=circle];
"(1, 4, 2, 3)" [shape=circle];
"(1, 4, 3, 2)" [shape=circle];
"(2, 1, 3, 4)" [shape=circle];
"(2, 1, 4, 3)" [shape=circle];
"(2, 3, 1, 4)" [shape=circle];
"(2, 3, 4, 1)" [shape=circle];
"(2, 4, 1, 3)" [shape=circle];
"(2, 4, 3, 1)" [shape=circle];
"(3, 1, 2, 4)" [shape=circle];
"(3, 1, 4, 2)" [shape=circle];
"(3, 2, 1, 4)" [shape=circle];
"(3, 2, 4, 1)" [shape=circle];
"(3, 4, 1, 2)" [shape=circle];
"(3, 4, 2, 1)" [shape=circle];
"(4, 1, 2, 3)" [shape=circle];
"(4, 1, 3, 2)" [shape=circle];
"(4, 2, 1, 3)" [shape=circle];
"(4, 2, 3, 1)" [shape=circle];
"(4, 3, 1, 2)" [shape=circle];
"(4, 3, 2, 1)" [shape=circle];
"(1, 2, 3, 4)" -- "(2, 1, 3, 4)"  [color=red];
"(1, 2, 3, 4)" -- "(2, 3, 4, 1)"  [color=blue];
"(1, 2, 3, 4)" -- "(4, 1, 2, 3)"  [color=blue];
"(1, 2, 4, 3)" -- "(2, 1, 4, 3)"  [color=red];
"(1, 2, 4, 3)" -- "(2, 4, 3, 1)"  [color=blue];
"(1, 2, 4, 3)" -- "(3, 1, 2, 4)"  [color=blue];
"(1, 3, 2, 4)" -- "(3, 1, 2, 4)"  [color=red];
"(1, 3, 2, 4)" -- "(3, 2, 4, 1)"  [color=blue];
"(1, 3, 2, 4)" -- "(4, 1, 3, 2)"  [color=blue];
"(1, 3, 4, 2)" -- "(3, 1, 4, 2)"  [color=red];
"(1, 3, 4, 2)" -- "(2, 1, 3, 4)"  [color=blue];
"(1, 3, 4, 2)" -- "(3, 4, 2, 1)"  [color=blue];
"(1, 4, 2, 3)" -- "(4, 1, 2, 3)"  [color=red];
"(1, 4, 2, 3)" -- "(3, 1, 4, 2)"  [color=blue];
"(1, 4, 2, 3)" -- "(4, 2, 3, 1)"  [color=blue];
"(1, 4, 3, 2)" -- "(4, 1, 3, 2)"  [color=red];
"(1, 4, 3, 2)" -- "(2, 1, 4, 3)"  [color=blue];
"(1, 4, 3, 2)" -- "(4, 3, 2, 1)"  [color=blue];
"(2, 1, 3, 4)" -- "(4, 2, 1, 3)"  [color=blue];
"(2, 1, 4, 3)" -- "(3, 2, 1, 4)"  [color=blue];
"(2, 3, 1, 4)" -- "(3, 2, 1, 4)"  [color=red];
"(2, 3, 1, 4)" -- "(3, 1, 4, 2)"  [color=blue];
"(2, 3, 1, 4)" -- "(4, 2, 3, 1)"  [color=blue];
"(2, 3, 4, 1)" -- "(3, 2, 4, 1)"  [color=red];
"(2, 3, 4, 1)" -- "(3, 4, 1, 2)"  [color=blue];
"(2, 4, 1, 3)" -- "(4, 2, 1, 3)"  [color=red];
"(2, 4, 1, 3)" -- "(3, 2, 4, 1)"  [color=blue];
"(2, 4, 1, 3)" -- "(4, 1, 3, 2)"  [color=blue];
"(2, 4, 3, 1)" -- "(4, 2, 3, 1)"  [color=red];
"(2, 4, 3, 1)" -- "(4, 3, 1, 2)"  [color=blue];
"(3, 1, 2, 4)" -- "(4, 3, 1, 2)"  [color=blue];
"(3, 2, 1, 4)" -- "(4, 3, 2, 1)"  [color=blue];
"(3, 4, 1, 2)" -- "(4, 3, 1, 2)"  [color=red];
"(3, 4, 1, 2)" -- "(4, 1, 2, 3)"  [color=blue];
"(3, 4, 2, 1)" -- "(4, 3, 2, 1)"  [color=red];
"(3, 4, 2, 1)" -- "(4, 2, 1, 3)"  [color=blue];
}

# + requirements that say the squares in the image below should also be squares in my graph
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide current input (no matter how rough) and desired output (hand sketch is OK)

Comment: It is not clear what your question is: 1. Do you want a recommendation for some other software than graphviz ( such questions are not allowed here ) or 2. Do you want help with graphviz

Comment: Your image shows 4 edges per node, but the example input only has 3 edges per node.

Comment: This might help: https://forum.graphviz.org/t/layout-algorithms/59